# Trying to use Appium on Ubuntu but getting node.js:134 error

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-14.04, sudo, appium

I've installed node with

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and appium with

```
sudo npm install -g appium
```

In both cases I was forced to use `sudo` as I was on Ubuntu.  The appium page at https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/README.md says don't use `sudo` but I believe that with Ubuntu it's ok (and necessary) to use `sudo` as directed on the node page at https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

When I try and start appium with `appium &` or even just

```
appium
```

I get

```
$ appium

node.js:134
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null
at Function.create (native)
at Object.inherits (util.js:425:27)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:63:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
at require (module.js:346:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js:1:90)
at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
```

I upgraded node but it hasn't seemed to help:

```
$ node -v                                                                                                     
v0.12.2
15:04:28 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Dropbox/_/appium_mobile_testing/appium master
$ appium
error: Appium will not work if used or installed with sudo. Please rerun/install as a non-root user. If you had to install Appium using `sudo npm install -g appium`, the solution is to reinstall Node using a method (Homebrew, for example) that doesn't require sudo to install global npm packages.
```

However when I uninstall node and then try re-installing it without sudo, as indicated, I get:

```
$ apt-get install nodejs
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I tried building node from source locally with

```
$ mkdir ~/local
$ ./configure --prefix=~/local
creating  ./icu_config.gypi
  { 'target_defaults': { 'cflags': [],
                   'default_configuration': 'Release',
                   'defines': [],
                   'include_dirs': [],
                   'libraries': []},
'variables': { 'clang': 0,
             'gcc_version': 48,
             'host_arch': 'x64',
             'icu_small': 'false',
             'node_install_npm': 'true',
             'node_prefix': '/home/durrantm/local',
             'node_shared_cares': 'false',
             'node_shared_http_parser': 'false',
             'node_shared_libuv': 'false',
             'node_shared_openssl': 'false',
             'node_shared_v8': 'false',
             'node_shared_zlib': 'false',
             'node_tag': '',
             'node_use_dtrace': 'false',
             'node_use_etw': 'false',
             'node_use_mdb': 'false',
             'node_use_openssl': 'true',
             'node_use_perfctr': 'false',
             'openssl_no_asm': 0,
             'python': '/usr/bin/python',
             'target_arch': 'x64',
             'uv_library': 'static_library',
             'uv_parent_path': '/deps/uv/',
             'uv_use_dtrace': 'false',
             'v8_enable_gdbjit': 0,
             'v8_enable_i18n_support': 0,
             'v8_no_strict_aliasing': 1,
             'v8_optimized_debug': 0,
             'v8_random_seed': 0,
             'v8_use_snapshot': 'true',
             'want_separate_host_toolset': 0}}
creating  ./config.gypi
creating  ./config.mk
$ make
...
$ make install
...
```

but it didn't seem to help:

```
$ npm install -g appium
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/durrantm/.npm/appium/1.3.7/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-49-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "appium"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/durrantm/Downloads/node/npm-debug.log
15:47:13 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Downloads/node master
$ appium 
error: Appium will not work if used or installed with sudo. Please rerun/install as a non-root user. If you had to install Appium using `sudo npm install -g appium`, the solution is to reinstall Node using a method (Homebrew, for example) that doesn't require sudo to install global npm packages.
```

I also did

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

and

```
sudo npm install -g appium

...
lots of compile outpout, not errors, seems ok
...
```

but still I get

```
$ appium
error: Appium will not work if used or installed with sudo. Please rerun/install as a non-root user. If you had to install Appium using `sudo npm install -g appium`, the solution is to reinstall Node using a method (Homebrew, for example) that doesn't require sudo to install global npm packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, **Appium** should not be installed with **sudo**.
And I won't recommend you to install **node** via **apt**, didn't work for me.

Better use **homebrew** - this will allow you to install **Appium** to a home directory without **sudo**. Try following:

1. Uninstall **node** that you previously installed with **apt**: `sudo apt-get remove node`
2. Follow instructions and [install homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew#installation). After that install **node** with: `brew install node`
3. Now try: `npm install -g appium`

And if you'll face permissions issues with **.npm** folder in home path, than use `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm` that you also mentioned.